# How to unomount file system mounted on "/"

Tags: linux, centos

I want to unmount `/` file system because my disk space is full and I want to extend 
my directory. Problem is my disk has errors and I have to run fsck on it.

When I try to unmount my directory, my file is mounted on:

```
/dev/mapper/vg_carlocentos-lv_root      100%      /
```

I want to be able to unmount the file system but I can't seem to unmount it.
It says resource is busy whenever  I try to unmount file:

```
umount /

init 1
umount: /: device is busy.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you in a position to reboot the machine? A dirty root filesystem will normally cause a file system check on startup.

Comment: you should be able to boot of off cd, and then manipulate your root volume

Comment: You can't unmount /. Think about it, how will you access the commands you need with / not there ?

Answer (score 7):

Your `/` is busy because you are attempting to unmount the root filesystem of the system you are actively running. The only way to cleanly do what you are thinking of doing is booting from another system & then mount the one you need to clean it & extend the volume.

Comment: You can typically use either a LiveCD or the installation media and boot into recovery mode.